# Перестали работать стили

Tags: html, css, laravel

Делаю свой первый блог на Laravel. В один момент перестали работать стили. То есть для левой части, самой обертки блока авторизации работает, а для label и input не хочет. В чем проблема?

```css
body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 background: rgba(197, 215, 235, 0.39);
}

* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
 max-width: 1140px;
 width: 100%;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
 margin: 0 auto;
 margin-top: 230px;
}

.about .title {
 font-weight: 700;
 font-size: 28px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 line-height: 32px;
 text-align: center;
 margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.about .text {
 font-size: 16px;
 color: #626d7a;
 line-height: 20px;
 text-align: center;
 width: 530px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 margin-bottom: 60px;
}

.authorize-block {
 height: 600px;
 width: 360px;
 box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px rgba(89, 89, 89, 0.2);
 padding: 20px;
}

.authorize-block label {
 font-size: 16px;
 margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.authorize-block input {
 width: 300px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
...
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css">
...


<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="about">
    <div class="title">
     Установите наше приложение
    </div>
    <div class="text">
     Установите официальное мобильное приложение и оставайтесь в курсе новостей Ваших друзей, где бы Вы ни находились.
    </div>
    <div class="image">
     <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/iBM0M-qUDU4HmrpyWGzDoRua3VjPEG2UFlPl-KGWuMv7fLL9IMvRFoIUsdcF9mnNORs=w720-h310-rw" alt="">
    </div>
   </div>
      
   <div class="authorize">
    <div class="authorize-block">
     <form action="{{ route('reg_submit') }}" method="POST">
      {{ csrf_field() }}
      <div>
       <label for="name">Ваше имя:</label><br>
       <input id="name" type="text" name="name" placeholder="имя">
      </div>

      <div>
       <label for="surname">Ваша фамилия:</label><br>
       <input id="surname" type="text" name="surname" placeholder="фамилия">
      </div>

      <div>
       <label for="email">Ваш email:</label><br>
       <input id="email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="email">
      </div>

      <div>
       <label for="password">Ваш пароль:</label><br>
       <input id="password" type="password" name="password"></input>
      </div>
      <button type="submit">Зарегистрироваться!</button>
     </form>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: В Вашем примере все работает. Поставил красный текст и он успешно применился. Насколько я помню в laravel стили подключаются через laravel-mix, который использует webpack

У себя в проекте подключаю так:
 `<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ mix('css/app.css') }}">`

Comment: @radar4ick, решил тоже поставить цвет тексту и удивительным образом все остальные стили тоже применились, наверное, магия